# Magento 2 Adding a block

Tags: magento2, blocks, product-collection, custom-block

I'm following the exercises of "Magento2 development cookbook".
In the part of "Adding a block of new products" (previously to that all works fine). I have:

*app/code/Packt/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Helloworld Landingspage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <remove name="wishlist_sidebar" /> <!-- THIS DOESN'T WORKS -->
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Packt\HelloWorld\Block\Landingspage" name="landingsblock" template="Packt_HelloWorld::landingspage.phtml" /> <!-- THIS WORKS -->
            <block class="Packt\HelloWorld\Block\Newproducts"  name="newproducts"  template="Packt_HelloWorld::newproducts.phtml" /><!-- THIS DOESN'T WORKS -->
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

*app/code/Packt/HelloWorld/Block/Newproducts.php*

```
<?php
namespace Packt\HelloWorld\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Newproducts extends Template
{
    private $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_logger = $context->getLogger();
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getProducts() {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();

        $this->_logger->info('YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY');
        //$this->_logger->info();

        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setOrder('created_at')
            ->setPageSize(5);

    return $collection;
}
```

}

---

*app/code/Packt/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/newproducts.php*

```
<h2>New Products</h2>

<ul>
    <?php foreach ($block->getProducts() as $product): ?>
        <li><?php echo $product->getName() ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This shows the title `New Products`?

Comment: no, it's shows the content of landingspage.phtml but not the newproducts.phtml

Comment: Did you clear Magento Cache,  remove `var/view_preprocessed`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if you **change `templates/newproducts.php` from php to phtml file**. I saw this is our mistake.

Clear Magento Cache, remove `var/view_preprocessed`. And try again.

Comment: @Muribury if my answer is helpful, you can accept it as the solution.